# Do OpenMesh circulators guarantee a specific order?

Tags: c++, openmesh

OpenMesh provides circulators to iterate over neighboring elements. The FaceVertex iterator is an example, which iterates over the vertices of a given face. My question is, does this circulator provide a specific, reproducible order of the face's vertices?

There are many operations that can happen on the mesh, including face/vertex insertions/deletions, edge collapse, etc. which all result in some internal reindexing of the elements. Assuming a face itself is unchanged but its neighborhood is, would its FaceVertex give the face's vertices in the original order? Whether the vertices internal indices were changed is irrelevant as long as they come in the same order, starting from the same corner of the face.